# Where in Seattle can I withdraw Euros?

Tags: usa, money, seattle

I will be visiting Seattle next week and I really need to withdraw cash but in Euros. Where can I do that with a foreign bank card with small fee?

Comment: I would be surprised if there were any other way than a currency exchange office (or a bank offering currency exchange services). But why do you actual need to get Euro’s in Seattle? If you plan to travel, withdrawing euros upon arrival surely would be simpler. You may find an ATM delivering euros or other currencies at the airport, but I doubt it.

Comment: sounds like an X-Y problem - I cannot imagine any reasons to need euro cash in Seattle. What do you really want to  accomplish?

Comment: In the 7 years I was in the US, I have never seen a bank (even in a major international hub like Houston, Los Angeles, Austin, Dallas, Chicago) carry foreign currency.

Answer (score 5):

Your bank card is only good on ATMs and POS machines; and since there are no ATMs in Seattle that dispense EUR, there is little or no hope there.

Your next option, is to possibly try to get a cash advance against a credit card. However, this will have to be given to you again in USD and not EUR since banks in the US rarely (if at all) carry anything but USD (assuming you can find one to do a cash advance for you against your foreign issued credit card).

Your best option is to bring the euros with you. Make sure you declare the amount at customs if it is above USD 10,000 otherwise you may end up forfeiting *all* notes and currencies you have on your person, if subjected to a search. It is safer to declare it.

No business in Seattle will accept Euro notes (excepting perhaps major hotel chains) and even if done so, it will be at exorbitant rates. You really need to think about dealing in USD when in the US (or using your card directly - for example, at the POS machine or ATM).

Finally, make sure you inform your bank that you are traveling to the US and your travel dates. Some may block your card (or otherwise restrict it) assuming it was stolen if its used abroad.

Answer (score -4):

Pretty much every bank and currency exchange should have Euros in stock. Of course the amount may be limited so you may have to return later to pick up the currency you want/need.

Most if not all banks will have exchange rates and fees posted either in their offices and/or online.

Comment: Are you serious about banks? This is news to me

Comment: It's unlikely that a random bank branch in Seattle would have euros on hand, but you can probably call ahead and find a branch that does foreign exchange and/or can preorder.  Expect to get gouged on the exchange rates though -- currency exchanges will be less bad.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen I've never seen a bank in a civilised nation that doesn't exchange between major world currencies. Heck, I've been able to get Dollars and Euros in backwaters in Indonesia.

Comment: @jpatokal in my experience banks offer better rate than exchange bureaus. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @jwenting I think you’re completely mistaken. The vast majority of banks in the USA will. It have foreign currency on hand.

Comment: Currency exchanges, yes. US Banks, not very likely (some will, but this is rare enough that it's clearly advertised if they do).

Comment: It will depend if a US bank branch has any foreign cash on hand, usually you'll have to call ahead or wait a few days while they arrange for a drop from the regional branch. I would imagine a random Seattle bank would likely have some Canadian dollars, but less likely to have euros.

Comment: (-1) Oh, dear. You must have the USA confused with almost every other country. The OP will probably have to go to the _main_ local office of a major bank. Even if branches will exchange Euros into dollars, there is _zero_ reason to believe they have Euros on hand to go the other way. I wouldn't even expect CDN$. Also, the fees and exchange rate will be terrible. I recommend the OP call and Google extensively, not just to find which branch has Euro cash (may need 24 hour notice!) but to compare fees/rates.